# Android Studio Error "Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.8."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

An error occurred after I downloaded version 6.8 and the latest version of Gradle.

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> < Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
> << Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl...

What do I have to do?

I'm attaching more details in the added pictures.
[image: Error message part 1]
[image: Error message part 2]
[image: Gradle Settings]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73034758/5040556

Answer (score 23):

The error:

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.8.

Likely means:

- Your "\gradle"-folder is missing from your project folder:
  *(**Note**: Not to be mistaken for the "**.gradle**"-folder which is a different folder)*

  ***Solution:***
  **Get a copy of the "\gradle"-folder** from another working project (or create a new project).

Or:

- Your "\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties" has an incorrect value in the "distributionUrl=":

  ***Solution:***
  **Change the value in "\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties"** to
  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip`

---

I hade the same problem after moving my project to another computer:

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.8.
>
> Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
> [Gradle Settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2cfF.png)

Clicking on the "Gradle Settings"-link opened the Gradle settings Window, but the Gradle JDK was already correctly set to `version 11`:
[image: Gradle Settings.]

So my next step was to check the Project Structure:
[image: Project Structure]

And update the Gradle Version to `7.0.2`:
[image: Gradle Version]

But that led to this error instead:
[image: \gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties]

> ¤ What went wrong:
> An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> » Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
> » Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 6.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in D:\Files\Code-Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-7.0.2-all.zip

Now the error points me towards a problem within the "\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties"-file.

Looking into that I found out the real problem - the "\gradle"-folder was completely missing.
*(**Note**: The "**\.gradle**"-folder is not the same as the "**\gradle**"-folder)*

**Copying the "\gradle"-folder from another project solved my problems.**

Now my "\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties"-file looks like this:

[image: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip]

Comment: This is a good source: https://sandny.com/2021/07/05/minimum-supported-gradle-version/

Comment: Thanks @ola! This is a very tricky issue, because error message in AS is misleading & wrong - root of the problem is not the wrong graddle version, problem is as you've correctly mentioned that `\gradle` folder is missing!!! But AS is silent about it, so it is hard to notice - I haven't realized it, until I've read your comment. Ofc `Invalidate cache and restart` does not help in this case, despite being a popular advice. Only after I'we copied `\graddle` folder from the other project it worked. Thanks again. Googlers should do something about their buggy AS and ambiguous error messages

Comment: @qkx - I just glad that my troubleshooting notes helped someone more than myself...

Answer (score 8):

Next update the Gradle Version in Android Studio select invalidate cache and restart solve the issue.
Go to Menu File->Invalidate cache..-> Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Go to gradle wrapper properties
[image]

In the distribution url line change gradle version from 6.5 to 7.0.2 or the current version when you see this

Comment: Thank you, the Gradle version in the project structure saved me

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the gradle version in your system is less than your project's gradle verion. That's the reason why it is unable to compile your project.

> **System gradle version** < **Project's gradle version**

So there are 2 solutions here,

1. Change the distribution URL in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in the `android/gradle/wrapper` directory to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip`.
2. Update your gradle plugin. If you use some environment variable, download the latest verion from [Gradle | Manual Installation](https://gradle.org/install/#manually) and replace it with your current one. Don't forget to update the `path` variable in system properties.