# Flutter Downloader: Failed to apply plugin class 'org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.KtlintBasePlugin'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-downloader

After upgrading to Flutter 3.3.7, and running "flutter pub outdated && flutter pub upgrade" I tried to build my app as usual. But then this showed up. "A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_downloader'". I added a new issue in https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/748 as well. Any ideas what could possibly go wrong? Thanks in advance.

***DEBUG CONSOLE RESULTS:***
build type: release, signining with release config..
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/xx/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.9.0/android/build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_downloader'.

> Failed to apply plugin class 'org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.KtlintBasePlugin'.
> Current version of plugin supports minimal Gradle version: 6.8

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/xx/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 474
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_downloader'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Cannot invoke method substring() on null object
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
> "

***Flutter Doctor Results:***
(Mac Book Air 13" M1 processor )

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.3.7 on channel stable at /Users/xx/development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision e99c9c7cd9 (33 hours ago), 2022-11-01 16:59:00 -0700
• Engine revision 857bd6b74c
• Dart version 2.18.4
• DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at /Users/xx/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
• ANDROID_HOME = /Users/xx/Library/Android/sdk
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14A400
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.52.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31) (emulator)
• macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm
• Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.87

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed this solution:

"Get a copy of the "\gradle"-folder from another working project (or create a new project)."

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862628/16703736)

Changing the gradle-wrapper.properties to >6.8 fixed it.